# How to call nodeJS API from Angular CLI at localhost with different port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI latest version and nodeJS as well, both running in localhost as different project and different port number, Angular (4200) and NodeJS (8088), added proxy settings in angular following this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjmZPPKaj6A ), then run command `npm start`.

[image]

now listens my nodeJs port number and getting response in error block.

[image]

When I run http://localhost:4200/api/sessin in browser, getting response on the screen.

example : `{"message":"session expired"}`

app.component.js

```
import { Component,Inject  } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './hero-form/hero-form.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    private url = "/api/sessin";
    data:any = {};
    constructor(private http:Http){
        console.log("constructor");
        this.fetchData();
    }
    getData(){
        return this.http.get(this.url).map((res:Response)=>res.json());
    }
    fetchData(){
        this.getData().subscribe(data=>{
            console.log(data);
            this.data = data;
        })
    }
}
```

proxy.conf.json

```
{
    "/api":{
        "target":"http://localhost:8088",
        "secure":false,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

nodeJS - api.js

```
router.get('/sessin', function(req,res,next){
    if(!req.session.userId){
        return res.status(401).json({"message":"session expired"});
    }else{
        return res.status(200).json({"userId":req.session.userId,"message":"LoggedIn"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your proxy-config files

Comment: @iambatman - added my proxy.conf.json file

Comment: You are missing a `/` in api. It should be `/api/*`

Comment: It's in your proxy-config.json file

Comment: Same after add /api/* - restarted node and angular too.

Comment: Did you added the proxy in package.json file

Comment: Yes - `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`

Comment: Still the same error in console??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161924/discussion-between-151291-and-iam-batman).